# Transfer function of an op-amp circuit with inverting feedback and dual input

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, differential-amplifier

Given the below circuit containing two ideal op-amps, how can I find the transfer function? I am confused by the \$-K\$ op-amp. Typically we need to find a transfer function like $$V_0 = f(v_1,v_2)$$

[image]

Comment: @Colin Where do you get unity gain from? K is an unknown, so the gain could be anything.

Comment: @Colin It's not unity gain. If it were unity, then you wouldn't need it anyway, because the op-amp is quite capable of maintaining its output even under load.

Comment: (Can't edit my comment after 5 minutes but thanks for the correction everyone) K simply states a specific constant gain, but in this case, an inverting constant gain with –K. What I'd probably do is imagine this as a block diagram like something you would find in a control system.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies! So basically that means the function should look like something V_O = v1 - K v2?

Comment: Ask yourself, “Does V1 or R1 have any effect on the output?”;given that -K is an ideal amplifier. @jimmy_p

Comment: @RussellH Ohh okay got you! Thanks

Comment: For me it is a nonlinear bistable circuit, so it cannot be defined a transfer function.

Comment: There is no positive feed back so cannot be bi-stable. It is linear @Franc and does have a TF Vo/V2.

Comment: Vo=V1(R1+R2)/[2R1+K(R1+R2)]+V2R2/[R1(K+1)]

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found using the classical feedback formula for the closed-loop gain Acl (Aol: Open-loop gain).

Using this approach we must not consider the signal source V1 - under the assumption (as mentioned in the task description) that the gain block "-K" is an ideal amplifier with zero output resistance.

**Vo/V2=Acl=Hi[Aol/(1+HfAol)** with input damping factor **Hi** and feedback factor **Hf**.

For an ideal opamp with infinite Aol this expression rduces to

**Acl=Hi/Hf**

with **Hi=-R2/(R1+R2)** and **Hf=[R1/(R1+R2)]+K** (two negative feedback ways).

Therefore: **Acl=Vo/V2=-R2/[R1 + K(R1+R2)]**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The block marked \$-K\$ will have a zero ohm output impedance. The implication of this is that \$V_1\$ is an output or a dummy input and, can be ignored in the calculation of the transfer function.

Start by looking at what \$-K\$ does and why it has a minus sign. Basically it produces and inverted signal at the non-inverting input of the op-amp. This turns an ideal op-amp with infinite open-loop gain into a regular amplifier of finite gain.

Basically, it's asking you (in a round about way) to derive the TF of an inverting op-amp circuit when the op-amp doesn't have infinite open-loop gain. Hint: there are dozens of proofs of this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the superpositiom pronciple I get:

[image]

Comment: Please, can you explain the used expression for V+. I think that the voltage V+ is determined by Vo only under the assumption that the block "-K" is an ideal amplifier with zero output resistance (no influnce from V1).

Comment: In the second case V+ is the arithmetic mean of the two input signals i.e. V1 and -KVo, if I'm not mistaken, correct me if I'm wrong since I wrote from memory, thanks.

Comment: If the block "-K" is an ideal voltage source, the voltage at the non-inv. input is V+=-Vo*K, independent on the signal V1.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately each amplifier has its output resistance...